# fgetcsv does not read entire row of CSV file

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file that looks like the following:

```
CODE;GROEP;SOORT;VOLGNR;REFERENCE;OMSCHRIJVING;PRIJS;STOCK;KOSTCOD1;KOSTBED1;KOSTCOD2;KOSTBED2;KOSTCOD3;KOSTBED3;KOSTCOD4;KOSTBED4;KOSTCOD5;KOSTBED5;EANCODE
101BE1573098;101;BE;1573098;A3L791B50CM-GRY;Belkin Patch Cable Cat5E assembled 0.5m;0,68;0;;;;;;;;;;;
101DE083104;101;DE;083104;083104;Kabel USB micro -B stekker USB-A 2.0 OTG 11cm;1,52;0;;;;;;;;;;;
101DE83510;101;DE;83510;83510;DELOCK Cable RJ45 Cat.5e SFTP angled / angled 0.5 m;2,21;0;;;;;;;;;;;4043619835102
101DE83511;101;DE;83511;83511;DELOCK Cable RJ45 Cat.5e SFTP angled / angled 1 m;2,81;0;;;;;;;;;;;4043619835119
101DE83512;101;DE;83512;83512;DELOCK Cable RJ45 Cat.5e SFTP angled / angled 2 m;4,1;0;;;;;;;;;;;4043619835126
```

I am using the following code to access the CSV file

```
$fh = fopen($local_file, 'r');

if ($fh) {
$line = 0;
while ( ($row = fgetcsv($fh)) !== false ) {

    if ($line == 0) {
        $line++;
        continue;
    }
    $values = explode( ';', $row[0] );
    echo $row[0];
    echo "</br>";
}
```

When I execute I get this:

```
101BE1573098;101;BE;1573098;A3L791B50CM-GRY;Belkin Patch Cable Cat5E assembled 0.5m;0
101DE083104;101;DE;083104;083104;Kabel USB micro -B stekker USB-A 2.0 OTG 11cm;1
101DE83510;101;DE;83510;83510;DELOCK Cable RJ45 Cat.5e SFTP angled / angled 0.5 m;2
101DE83511;101;DE;83511;83511;DELOCK Cable RJ45 Cat.5e SFTP angled / angled 1 m;2
101DE83512;101;DE;83512;83512;DELOCK Cable RJ45 Cat.5e SFTP angled / angled 2 m;4
```

As you can see, the row ends at the ',' in column 'PRIJS'. Does anyone have any idea why it does this?

Comment: `fgetcsv($fh, 0, ";")`

Comment: @E_p I wasn't aware that it splits records by default, I was trying to do it manually. This was indeed the problem. If you put it as an answer I will mark it. Thank you

Comment: CSV stands for "comma separated variables" file. Your variables file gets separated at a comma. Sounds legit unless you manually set the separator.

Comment: So posted an answer no acceptance for it.

Comment: @E_p There was a waiting time still at the time. Accepted it now though. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

fgetcsv can parse based on different delimiters (3rd parameter)
eg: `fgetcsv($fh, 0, "delimiter")`

So to solve that problem:

```
<?php
    while ( ($row = fgetcsv($fh, 0, ";")) !== false ) {
        // ...
    }
```